# Dynamic Report taking too much time to export pdf/excel report

Tags: java, jasper-reports, dynamic-reports

I have fetched **26000** records from database and took into a list, while exporting that list as PDF or excel taking too much time.

```
report.toXlsx(new FileOutputStream(fileForXls));
```

above line takes 30 to 40 seconds to execute.
How to reduce its execution time?

**Code**

```
 public synchronized String execute(){
            JasperReportBuilder report = DynamicReports.report();//a new report
            StyleBuilder boldStyle  = DynamicReports.stl.style().bold();
            StyleBuilder boldCenteredStyle = DynamicReports.stl.style(boldStyle)
                    .setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);

            StyleBuilder columnTitleStyle  = DynamicReports.stl.style(boldCenteredStyle)
                    .setBorder(DynamicReports.stl.pen1Point())
                    .setBackgroundColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);


            report
              .columns(
                  Columns.column("Sr #", "srNumber",DataTypes.integerType()).setWidth(40).setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.LEFT),
                  Columns.column("IR No", "irNo", DataTypes.stringType()).setWidth(130),
                  Columns.column("Status", "state", DataTypes.stringType()));

            report.columnGrid()
                    .setIgnorePageWidth(true)
                    .title( // title of the report
                    Components
                            .text("IR Report")
                            .setStyle(boldCenteredStyle)
                            .setHorizontalAlignment(
                                    HorizontalAlignment.CENTER))
                    .setColumnTitleStyle(columnTitleStyle)
                    .highlightDetailEvenRows()
                    .pageFooter(
                            Components.pageXofY().setStyle(
                                    boldCenteredStyle))
                    .setDataSource(createDataSource());

            String fileForXls="D:/IRReport.xlsx";

            report.toXlsx(new FileOutputStream(fileForXls)); //time consuming code

return SUCCESS;
}

private JRDataSource createDataSource() {
    DRDataSource dataSource = new DRDataSource("srNumber","irNo", "state");
    List<ResultHeaderBean> data1= irdao.getAllRecords(); //returns List of 26000 records
    int count=0;
    for(ResultHeaderBean data:data1 ){
        count=++count;
        dataSource.add(count,crdata.getIrNumber(), crdata.getStatus());
    }
    return dataSource;
}
```

Comment: This is still 866 item per seconds.The full code took 30sec ? Reading from the DB included ?

Comment: reading from DB takes 1 or 2 seconds only, report.toXlxs() takes 30 seconds

Comment: You can look at JRFileVirtualizer

Comment: Did you try to use profiler?

Comment: I didn't use profiler @AlexK

Comment: Did you try to use simplest exporter (export to csv, for example)? What is execution time in this case?  Did you try to simplify report (remove styles)? I think you have to use profiler, maybe you faced some bug of engine/library